# UIView 'falling rain' transparent overlay that can be clicked through?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'd like to create a `UIView` which will animate falling rain, which should be above all other views, at the very front, but transparent, and it shouldn't register taps or interaction at all, so tapping the UI behind it should behave exactly as it does now, before I've implemented it. It'd act as an overlay, and nothing more.

Is this as simple as setting `UserInteractionEnabled` to `NO`, or is there more to it? Do I need to subclass `UIView`, or override something, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, set `userInteractionEnabled = NO;` No need to subclass UIView. e.g.:

```
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5];
[self.view addSubview:overlay];
```

Comment: So this won't simply ignore taps on the view, it'll pass them through to whatever control is beneath them at that position?

Comment: Try it out, should be fine :)

Comment: Haven't gotten round to it yet but I'll keep you posted ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of hittest after adding the transparent subview as @zenith has explained.

The implementation of hitTest:withEvent: in UIResponder does the following:

It calls pointInside:withEvent: of self

If the return is NO, hitTest:withEvent: returns nil. the end of the story.

If the return is YES, it sends hitTest:withEvent: messages to its subviews. it starts from the top-level subview, and continues to other views until a subview returns a non-nil object, or all subviews receive the message.

If a subview returns a non-nil object in the first time, the first hitTest:withEvent: returns that object. the end of the story.

If no subview returns a non-nil object, the first hitTest:withEvent: returns self
This process repeats recursively, so normally the leaf view of the view hierarchy is returned eventually.

However, you might override hitTest:withEvent to do something differently. In many cases, overriding pointInside:withEvent: is simpler and still provides enough options to tweak event handling in your application.